# bootstrap 4 tooltip with br doen't work properly

Tags: bootstrap-4

bootstrap 4 tooltip with html tag 
show the tag in hover.

in previous version of bootstrap works fine but in version 4 doesn't work.
what is missed?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray! <br> test">Hover over me</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In all bootstrap version before 4 works fine but in v4 should add attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this page the behaviour is depending on an extra data attribute:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

Add this to your anchor tag and it will work:
data-html="true"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Hooray! <br> test">Hover over me</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```